# The Android xmlns and the Android API

Tags: android, xml

I new to programming Android apps and trying to understand the difference between the Android xmlns and Android API. Is it right to say that the xlmns is subset of the Android API?

I've also been trying to find a overview off all properties you can modify with the Android xmlns, but can seem to find it. Is this because the API serves as a documentation for this as well?

Answer (score 1):

XMLNS and Android API are completely different.

XML namespaces are used for providing uniquely named elements and attributes in an XML document. `xmlns:android` describes the android namespace.

Android API can be simply understood as the Android version, and new features are added in every release.

Answer (score 0):

xmlns has nothing to do with Android.  Its an xml property that specifies what the namespace for an XML document is so it can be validated properly.

Comment: Thanks. When declaring a namespace: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android, does this referring to the API, and I, therefore, can set the attributes for the different resources?